# In ios13, the new KeyWindow will automatically disappear after display

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios13

I want to show a UIAlertController in the new window,but it automatically disappear after display.

My project is created with xcode10.x.
Then I upgrade Xcode to 11.0, and run my project in ios13

```
UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithWindowScene:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.windowScene];
    window.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    vc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    window.rootViewController = vc;

    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *confirmAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Confirm" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
    [alertController addAction:confirmAction];

    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [vc presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The window and the AlertController automatically disappear after display.

If I retain the window, like:

```
static UIWindow *win;
win = window;
```

The window will never disappear.

Comment: Where is that code? Show some context please. Why are you making a window?

Comment: In ios12, the window and alertController will disappear after I chicking the `confirmAction`

Comment: Because I want to pop up more than one UIAlertController at a time

Comment: I see. That's a good answer, but I think you should just stop wanting that. It's forbidden and it's a wrong thing to do. Rethink your interface.

Comment: Please [search on this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=UIAlertController%20disappears). I'm amazed how many are reporting this exact same problem from this exact same attempt to misuse UIAlertController.

Comment: Thank you. I seem to have found a way to present more than one UIAlertController.

Comment: @huangqc could you please share your solution, I am trying to present only one alert controller, and the new window gets dismissed automatically.